# Upload image to Skype BOT

Tags: c#, bots, skype, botframework, skype-bots

I have a bot develop with Microsoft Bot Framework, and in Debug run correctly

After the install on Skype, after the upload the image I have a link like this

```
https://df-apis.skype.com/v2/attachments/0-eus-d4-7e19a097c62f5fc21dd53eabfa19d85e/views/original
```

The code is very simply and run without skype

```
if ((activity.Attachments != null) && (activity.Attachments.Count > 0))
{

      analysisResult = await AnalyzeUrl(activity.Attachments[0].ContentUrl);

}
........
```

How do I find the picture that I sent?

Comment: What is `AnalyzeUrl`? Can you share the code for that?

Comment: @MartinKearn AnalyzeUrl is a function who call CognitiveServices, this function run correctly. I think the problems are in the Skype security policies

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [this comment](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/662#issuecomment-232223965), to fetch an attachment, the GET request should contain *JwtToken* of the bot as authorization header:

```
var attachment = activity.Attachments?.FirstOrDefault();
if (attachment?.ContentUrl != null)
{
    using (var connectorClient = new ConnectorClient(new Uri(activity.ServiceUrl)))
    {
        var token = await (connectorClient.Credentials as MicrosoftAppCredentials).GetTokenAsync();
        var uri = new Uri(attachment.ContentUrl);
        using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
        {
            if (uri.Host.EndsWith("skype.com") && uri.Scheme == Uri.UriSchemeHttps)
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", token);
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/octet-stream"));
            }
            else
            {
                httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue(attachment.ContentType));
            }

            var attachmentData = await httpClient.GetByteArrayAsync(uri);
            analysisResult = await AnalyzeUrl(attachmentData);
        }
    }    
}
```

That means you have to change the `AnalyzeUrl` to accept the image data instead of URL. I believe CognitiveServices, you are using, are able to accept the image data.