# In Skype bot framework Attachments Content null

Tags: skype, botframework, skypedeveloper

I'm trying to access the list of attachments sent by the user to the skype bot that I'm developing.

Here is how I access the attachment details ,

```
     public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> Post([FromBody]Activity message)
     {

        if (message.Attachments != null)
        {
            if (message.Attachments.Count > 0)
            {
                List<Attachment> attachmentList = message.Attachments.ToList();

                foreach (var item in attachmentList)
                {
                    var name = item.Name;
                    var content = item.Content;
                }
            }
        }
     }
```

But I get null for the following even though the attachment count is greater than zero,

```
   var name = item.Name;
   var content = item.Content;
```

Am I doing this right?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Upload image to Skype BOT](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38633676/upload-image-to-skype-bot)

Answer (score -2):

Maybe do something like this...

```
List<Attachment> attachmentList = message?.Attachments?.Where(x => x != null)?.ToList() ?? new List<Attachment>();
```

This would hopefully always set attachmentList to an empty list or a list containing non null items?